# Asp.Net Identity connecting to DB via Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am working on a legacy MVC application which initially had forms authentication via a custom class and implementation.  I have modified it and utilised Asp.Net Identity which is working as expected.

My requirement now is that this MVC application no longer should have direct access to the database.  So I have removed the connection string from the web.config and have been looking at making all database calls via calls to my web service (Asp.Net Web Api).

I have custom classes for:

- `UserStore`
- `RoleStore`
- etc

Please note I have a custom user class as it is a custom user table.

**Questions**

1) Is the correct way to achieve my goal? It's likely I will be overriding many methods which had previously used the IdentityDBContext such as:

```
public override Task<CustomUser> FindByIdAsync(int usrID)

public override Task<Customer> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
```

2) I am finding that

> FindByNameAsync()

is working as expected and the user is being passed to the method however FindByIdAsync() is passing userid as 0.  Why would FindByIdAsync() not be passing my actual userid?

To call `FindByIdAsync()` I am implementing a UserStore:

```
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore
    <
        CustomUser, 
        CustomRole, 
        int,
        CustomUserLogin, 
        CustomUserRole, 
        CustomUserClaim
    >
{
```

and then overriding `FindByIdAsync():`

```
public override Task<CustomUser> FindByIdAsync(int usrID)
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync("api/user/" + usrID).Result.Content;
        return response.ReadAsAsync<CustomUser>(
             new List<MediaTypeFormatter> {
                new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(),
                new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
            });
        //return base.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    }
```

The issue is that `usrID` is 0.

Comment: Welcome good sir. I'm sort of thinking that the first part of your question is _subject to opinion_ and if so harms the rest of your question (opinion questions are off-topic on SO).   The second part is more in line with SO and we may be able to help you there.  Can you show us _how_ you are calling `FindByIdAsync`?  e.g. have you put a breakpoint at the line when the method is called to find out why it is `0`?

Comment: Hi MickyD.  I have added some further details for my question 2.

With regards to question, I can see your point.  I was after some guidance/links to give me some comfort that I am not going about it in a long winded manner.

Comment: When you call that web service from FindByIdAsync don't you need to authorize your request to the webservice? Did you enable anonymous access to that particular method? Is that safe? Or is there something I am missing? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have this working, so my mvc application is using AspNet.Identity but for all the database calls it is calling my api.  The solution was indeed to implement IUserStore (and other interfaces as required) and there are a lot of answers and guides on the Internet for this.  A good starting point is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity